# Git problem about repositry ownership (see screenshot in posting)

Tags: git, visual-studio, repository, microchip, atmel

I use Git together with Microchip (Atmel) Studio. Recently, I needed to reinstall mentioned IDE. From that time on, i have to start the IDE as admin for some reason, else the project files won´t open. When I try to access my project repostory, I get an error message (Shown in attached screen shot). The soulution recomended in the error message doesn´t work.
Anybody an idea how to solve the problem?

TIA,
Harald
[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1419F.png)

I tried the solution recommended in the error message.